# NodeJS - Edit a csv cell

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I want to modify some cells in a CSV file and first read the file and get the data of the part I want. However there is a problem when it saves in that it flattens the rows and also turns the `;` characters into `,` also adding an extra comma to the line I modify.

How can I modify and save a certain cell's data?

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var parse = require('csv-parse');

var parser = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(err, data){

    var row0 = '' + data[0];
    var index = row0.split(',')[0];
    data[0] = index + ';' + 'Modified Cell Here' + ',' + row0.split(',')[2];

    fs.writeFile("./Sample.csv", data, function(err) { if(err) { return console.log(err); }}); 

    console.log(data);
});

fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/Sample.csv').pipe(parser);
```

The Sample.csv is:

```
0;123,abc
1;456,efg
2;789,hij
```

In the modified Sample.csv it returns as:

```
0;Modified Cell Here,abc,1,456,efg,2,789,hij
```

I was expecting this:

```
0;Modified Cell Here,abc
1;456,efg
2;789,hij
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you could join the array back with a newline before writing

snip::

```
data[0] = index + ';' + 'Modified Cell Here' + ',' + row0.split(',')[2];

var outputData = data.join('\n') ; 

fs.writeFile("./Sample.csv", outputData, function(err) { if(err) { return console.log(err); }});
```

::snip